# Different templates usage caused by changing the order in URLs (auth / registration)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-authentication, django-registration

I am using in my project  [built-in auth tools](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) and django-registration

I have my logout template at:

```
/accounts/templates/registration/logout.html
```

If urls.py looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
url(regex = r'^accounts/', view = include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
url(regex = r'^accounts/', view = include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
...
]
```

It uses my template. It's OK.

But if I reorganize url like:

```
 urlpatterns = [
...
url(regex = r'^accounts/', view = include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
url(regex = r'^accounts/', view = include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
...
]
```

It uses built-in admin logout template.

Why does it happen?

### Edit

In [their tutorial](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.3/hmac.html?highlight=unique#behavior-and-configuration) I see that they say about 'registration.backends.hmac.urls':

> **That URLconf also sets up the views from django.contrib.auth (login,
>   logout, password reset, etc.),** though if you want those views at a
>   different location, you can include() the URLconf
>   registration.auth_urls to place only the django.contrib.auth views at
>   a specific location in your URL hierarchy.

But when I open it, it seems to have no connection with auth urls/views:
**EDIT**: OK, now I see.

```
"""
URLconf for registration and activation, using django-registration's
HMAC activation workflow.

"""

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from .views import ActivationView, RegistrationView


urlpatterns = [
url(r'^activate/complete/$',
    TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='registration/activation_complete.html'
    ),
    name='registration_activation_complete'),
# The activation key can make use of any character from the
# URL-safe base64 alphabet, plus the colon as a separator.
url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>[-:\w]+)/$',
    ActivationView.as_view(),
    name='registration_activate'),
url(r'^register/$',
    RegistrationView.as_view(),
    name='registration_register'),
url(r'^register/complete/$',
    TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='registration/registration_complete.html'
    ),
    name='registration_complete'),
url(r'^register/closed/$',
    TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='registration/registration_closed.html'
    ),
    name='registration_disallowed'),
url(r'', include('registration.auth_urls')),
```

]

Comment: the built-in authentication support should be 'django.contrib.auth' in in your INSTALLED_APPS,

Comment: Yes, it is and I am using it. But i wonder, why registration interferes with it, despite it's urls.py which I'm using does not have any (for me) visible connection with django.contrib.auth.

It's written, that if you use django-registration, you don't have to add aut.contrib separately, because registration links it already.

When I remove django.contrib.auth.urls from urls all tests fail. So it does not link.

Comment: hmmm they do have connection which django User model for their authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [last url pattern](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration/blob/a336198021907b4d7bfa1a34cd4acc71d7456fd3/registration/backends/hmac/urls.py#L37) in `registration.backends.hmac.urls` includes [`registration.auth_urls`](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration/blob/master/registration/auth_urls.py), which provides urls for login, logout and so on.

```
url(r'', include('registration.auth_urls')),
```

If you include `django.contrib.auth.urls`, above the hmac urls, then the logout view from `django.contrib.auth` will be used. This view [uses a different template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L97), `registration/logged_out.html`. Since you haven't overridden this, the admin template is used.

Comment: Well, I must be blind, I didn't notice this line. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The django url dipatcher which maps urls to views checks urls in order from first to last:

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first
>   one that matches the requested URL.

So the order of the similar urls determinate which url is matched. I.e. the first is matched.